# Create site pages dynamically

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, primefaces

I'm building a blog application using JSF and Primefaces. I utilize Primefaces extension for CFKeditor to generate the content and save it to a database. Upon saving the blog, I would like to generate a webpage featuring it and add it to my domain. For example, if the Blog't title was "The Golden Ticket", I would like to programmatically generate the following page http://www.somedomain.com/blog/The_Golden_Ticket. A couple of possibilities I'm considering.

1. Hardcode the various tags to generate the page, insert blog content & title, save to the appropriate folder on the webserver.
2. Add a listener for anything www.somepage.com/blog/* dynamically generate the page on the fly and return to the user.

Please advise on the best method to go about accomplishing this goal.

Thank You!

Comment: Create one template page and fill it up with contents depending on the context by the backing beans.

Comment: How do  i return that template without changing the URL? I don't want the URL to change to www.somedomain.com/blog/template , but would like it to stay as the user typed it in.

Comment: The pages have no valid urls. You can access them by query params or as a REST resource.

Comment: Ok I think query params is what I was missing. thanks!